# JavaScript: remove a part of the code and remove an element when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on opening a window pop-up when I click on a link, but I have problems.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.overlay-trigger').click(function(){
        $('#expose-mask').fadeIn('fast',function()
        {
            $('.overlay-box').css({'display':'block'});
        });
    });
    $('#boxclose').click(function()
    {
        $('.overlay-box').animate({'top':'-200px'},500,function()
        {
            $('#expose-mask').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

my HTML code:

```
<div class="overlay-box">
 <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose"></a>
 <h1>Important message</h1>
 <p>
  Here comes a very important message for your user.
  Turn this window off by clicking the cross.
 </p>
</div>

<a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="#">Help</a>

<div id="expose-mask" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#expose-mask
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

.overlay-box
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#7F7F7F;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -khtml-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #333;
    z-index:101;
}

a.overlay-boxclose{
    float:right;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    background:transparent url(images/cancel.png) repeat top left;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-right:-30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.overlay-box h1{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #7F7F7F;
    margin:-20px -20px 0px -20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFEFEF;
    color:#EF7777;
    -moz-border-radius:20px 20px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Currently, if I click on my link, it will open the activator `overlay-trigger`

I'd like to remove these parts of my JavaScript code: http://prntscr.com/680zzd

I'd like that when the pop-up is open, if I click on my id `#expose-mask`, it closes the pop-up.

You can have a live preview here: nextgenfocus.com/test/ (click on the "Help" text at the bottom of the page to open the pop-up).

Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: there is no #expose-mask in your HTML code.

Comment: I edited it. Look here to have an idea of the code source: nextgenfocus.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is there. when you click on close button , you are changing position top:-200px of overlay-box, but when again you showing the popup you need to giving top:40% position (reset) as same in css. 
and you are missing close button text/image

```
<div class="overlay-box">
 <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose">close</a>
 <h1>Important message</h1>
 <p>
  Here comes a very important message for your user.
  Turn this window off by clicking the cross.
 </p>
</div>

<a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="#">Help</a>

<div id="expose-mask" style="display: none;"></div>
```

js code :

```
$(function() {
    $('.overlay-trigger').click(function(){
        $('#expose-mask').fadeIn('fast',function()
        {
            $('.overlay-box').css({'display':'block','top':'40%'});
        });
    });
    $('#boxclose').click(function()
    {
        $('.overlay-box').animate({'top':'-200px'},100,function()
        {
            $('#expose-mask').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qdumn7cs/)

Comment: I want to remove the animation and have something like this: http://community.invisionpower.com/register/ (click the "Privacy Policy" text).